# Find all solutions $x, y\in\Bbb Z^+$ of $xy + 5x - 8y = 79$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I would like some help understanding this question.   I have many similar questions to answer.  If I get some help with this one I believe I can do the rest.  Thank you in advance.

> Find all solutions $x, y\in\Bbb Z^+$ of $xy + 5x - 8y = 79$.

Comment: So we have $(x-8)(y+5)+40=79$ which is similar to $ab=39$.  What integer solutions are possible?

Comment: @abiessu I believe it should be an answer.

Answer (score 3):

note that $$x=8+\frac{39}{y+5}$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $(x-8)(y+5) = 39$. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

With $x, y\in\Bbb Z^+$ and considering $xy + 5x - 8y = 79$, begin by "completing the multiplication":  we have $x(y+5)-8y$, so to complete the multiplication, subtract enough from both sides to create $-8(y+5)$, which means subtract $40$ from both sides, yielding

$$x(y+5)-8(y+5)=79-40\\
(x-8)(y+5)=39$$

We have $39=1\cdot39=3\cdot13$ on the RHS, and since $x,y\gt 0$ we cannot have $y+5\le 5$, which means that $y+5=13,39$ and thus $y=8,34$, leaving $x-8=1,3$ or $x=9,11$.

Therefore the set of solutions in positive integers is $(x,y)=(9,34)$ or $(x,y)=(11,8)$.